# Commit in GitHub with AnkhSVN

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, github, ankhsvn

I'm starting this discusion, because i want to learn how to upload my projects in github or codeplex.

- I'm using Visual Studio 2008 SP! and .NET 3.5.
- I have installed AnkhSVN on my machine.
- I have an acount on Github.
- I have created a repository on github with my project name.

#### So here is the problem:

1. I'm starting my project and i Press in visual studio FIle menu: 
   `Subversion -> Add Solution to Subversion...`
2. On the choose repository dialog, I paste in the url for the repository on github.When the
3. It seems like everything is correct, because the dialog shows the default structure of a 
   repository, but when i press 'OK', a message appears:

> One of more of your local resources are out of date. You need to run update before proceed with the operation.

My questions are:

1. How to repair this isue?
2. How i can upload with ankhsvn my projects in any site.
3. Is there better GUI software alternative to default Git client.
4. What is the best way of svn control with visual studio projects.

If I wasn't clear, I can upload pictures with the steps how I get this error.

Thanks for the chanse to answer this question. 
For me will be great anyone to answer on any question that I posted.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use the command line.  This [tutorial](http://git-scm.com/book) is very well regarded.  You can also try [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/), which is a GUI integrated into Visual Studio.

Although Github has [experimental support](https://github.com/blog/966-improved-subversion-client-support) for the SVN protocol, I would not recommend it for anything serious.

Answer (score 0):

To use subversion client with Github following support link should help
https://help.github.com/articles/support-for-subversion-clients

Apart from this I would suggest you to use Github's windows client or 'SourceTree' and make a git repository instead of a subversion repository.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but answering this question incase someone else is trying to make this work. I had to get this working and this is what worked for me.

1. Create a repo in github (initialise it with a readme file etc).Or use an existing one
2. From the repository page, copy the Subversion checkout URL (Make sure this is the Subversion checkout URL and not the HTTPS or SSH URL)
3. Open/Create project you want to add and select File -> SubVersion -> Add Solution to Subversion
4. In the following window, enter the Repository Url that you have copied in step 2
5. Select the trunk of Subversion Repository you created and click Ok.

Thats it. you can now check in and out of the github repository using anknsvn fromt he pending changes window in visual studio